# почему страница dialogs не сохраняется при переходе по другому url адресу?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

При нажатии, допустим, на "Dimych" сам url меняется из ../dialogs на ../dialogs/1. По идеи, страница Dialogs должна так же отображаться, но по не понятной причине исчезает.

````
Родительский компонент:

import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';

import Profile from './components/Profile/Profile';
import Dialogs from './components/Dialogs/Dialogs';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';


const App = () => {
  return (
      <div className='app-wrapper'>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Header />
          <Navbar />

          <div className='app-wrapper-content'>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/dialogs' element={<Dialogs />}/>
              <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />}/>
            </Routes>
  
          </div>
            
        </BrowserRouter>
        
      </div>);
}

export default App;

Сама страница Dialogs:

import React from "react";
import s from './Dialogs.module.css';
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Dialogs = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={s.dialogs}>
            <div className={s.dialogsItems}>
                <div className={s.dialog + ' ' + s.active}>
                    <NavLink to="/dialogs/1">Dimych</NavLink>
                </div>

                <div className={s.dialog}>
                    <Link to="/dialogs/2">Bob</Link>
                </div>
              
                <div className={s.dialog}>
                    <Link to="/dialogs/3">Krit</Link>
                </div>

                <div className={s.dialog}>
                    <Link to="/dialogs/4">Veronika</Link>
                </div>
                
                <div className={s.dialog}>
                    <Link to="/dialogs/5">Valeriy</Link>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div className={s.messages}>
                <div className={s.message}>Hi</div>
                <div className={s.message}>How are you?</div>
                <div className={s.message}>Yo</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Dialogs```
````

Comment: Нет. `/dialogs` и `/dialogs/1` это 2 разных url.

Comment: Swad, а как иначе можно исправить это? просто /dialogs ведь есть в /dialogs/1. А что бы страница dialog пропадала, надо прописывать exact, а его нет и по идеи страница должна сохранятся

Comment: Ищется не подстроки, а строки целиком для определния адреса. Какого поведения и результатов вы хотите достичь, указывая в адресе `/dialogs/1`?

Comment: чтобы при нажатии на одну из ссылок в компоненте Dialogs, например на 'Dimych', страница Dialogs все так же оставалась, а не исчезала, менялся только url

Comment: Ну вот так напишите `path='/dialogs/:id'`

Comment: пробовал так написать, не получалось, но сейчас только увидел, что не прописал это же в другом файле! Спасибо!